# The add textures shortcut of node wrangler isn't working

Tags: node-editor

I checked the preferences and the node wrangler is enabled, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>T</kbd> don't work.

Comment: have you selected the node into which you want to plug the new ones?

Comment: what happens when you type those?

Comment: Do you try to use this functionality for the first time (which could mean you do it in a wrong way somehow), or did you use it in the past and it worked, but at some point it stopped working?

Comment: I forget to select the node in which I want to plug in the node wrangler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that I for forgot to select the node in which I want to plug the node wrangler. So the steps to properly use the node wrangler are:

1. Select the node where you need the wrangler
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>